# Why is heroku not accepting my "git push heroku master"?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

So I'm currently trying to deploy my django app to heroku, and I'm getting an error.
On my app I serve both static and media files from an AWS S3 bucket, and locally everything is working fine, but when I try to deploy to heroku I get this error:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_a4a811fd/manage.py", line 22, in 
 <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_a4a811fd/manage.py", line 18, in 
 main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in 
 execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in 
 execute
remote:            
 self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in 
 run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/
 collectstatic. py", line 187, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/
 collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
remote:            handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/
 collectstatic.py", line 338, in copy_file
remote:            if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, 
 source_storage):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/
 collectstatic.py", line 248, in delete_file
remote:            if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 469, in exists
remote:            
 self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, 
 Key=name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/client.py", line 395, in _api_call
remote:            return self._make_api_call(operation_name, 
 kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/client.py", line 695, in _make_api_call
remote:            request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/client.py", line 743, in 
 _convert_to_request_dict
remote:            api_params = self._emit_api_params(
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/client.py", line 772, in _emit_api_params
remote:            self.meta.events.emit(
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 357, in emit
remote:            return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, 
 **kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
remote:            return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
remote:            response = handler(**kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 238, in validate_bucket_name
remote:            if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not 
 VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
remote:        TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py 
 collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve 
 this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this 
 application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

These are my settings.py:

```
PRODUCTION = True

if PRODUCTION:
    # AWS S3 SETTINGS
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
        'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
    }
    AWS_HEADERS = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
    STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'joaoLina.storage_backend.MediaStorage'
    MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, 'media')
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I read that sometimes this problem happens because STATIC_ROOT is not set, but that is not the case. And I know I could just do:

```
$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

but this way the problem will still be there.

I did locally:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
python3 manage.py test
```

and everything went just fine with 0 issues.

So I really don't know where is the problem, if someone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: please paste the errors as text instead of images.

Comment: Is it better like this?

Comment: Your `git push` *successfully sent your commits to Heroku*. Heroku then thought about them for a while, and *Heroku* said "I don't like these commits" and told you why. Git relayed Heroku's errors to you, prefixed with `remote:`. Git then closed everything down with the commits not added because *Heroku* rejected them. Don't blame Git!

Comment: I edited the name of the question. Thanks for the explanation.